# Why does spring rest controller return unauthorized when no security has been set

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I have start a spring boot application. I added a rest controller like this

```
@RestController
public class EmailController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/2", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public int getNumber() {
        return 2;
    }
}
```

When I call the url http://localhost:8080/2 I get a 401 exception.

```
{"timestamp":1498409208660,"status":401,"error": 
 "Unauthorized","message":"Full authentication is 
 required to access this resource", "path":"/2"}
```

That I have absolutely no security set whats so ever. This is a clean spring boot project! Why am I receiving an unauthorized exception.

Comment: add the dependency tree

Comment: if u add spring security, by default basic authentication is ON in spring boot.

Comment: I came here with this problem and, yes, Spring Security was in my dependency graph. This was a copy/paste error.

Answer (score 2):

You configured no authentication (Form Login, HTTP Basic, ...) so the default AuthenticationEntryPointis used, see Spring Security API [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/apidocs/org/springframework/security/config/annotation/web/configurers/ExceptionHandlingConfigurer.html#authenticationEntryPoint-org.springframework.security.web.AuthenticationEntryPoint-):

Sets the AuthenticationEntryPoint to be used.

If no authenticationEntryPoint(AuthenticationEntryPoint) is specified, then defaultAuthenticationEntryPointFor(AuthenticationEntryPoint, RequestMatcher) will be used. The first AuthenticationEntryPoint will be used as the default is no matches were found.

If that is not provided defaults to Http403ForbiddenEntryPoint.
You can set the AuthenticationEntryPoint as @ksokol wrote or configure a authentication, which defines a AuthenticationEntryPoint.

Answer (score 1):

Add   @EnableWebSecurity annotation in your main class it will ignore default security to access that application.

sample code is below:

```
@EnableWebSecurity
    @SpringBootApplication

    public class SampleApplication {
        SampleApplication (){}
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            SpringApplication.run(SampleApplication .class, args);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

For people looking for a solution. I added this to my application.yml

```
security: 
  ignored: /**
```

Comment: If you don't want security why did you add spring security to your application?

Comment: I didn't! I am using spring boot and I think it enables it by default because I can't find any spring security in my project.

Comment: That will only be enabled if a Spring Security dependency is on the class path else security isn't even activated. So there must be a dependency that is pulling in Spring Security.

Comment: I bump into the same error with the latest Spring Boot release. I have been searching around but haven't found the root cause yet. It doesn't hit the REST controller at all. I can see the request being logged in the catalina access log (40x error) but nothing in catalina.[out|log] at all. This really makes debugging very difficult. Google doesn't yield any structured way of debugging this error. So it sounds like a configuration issue but which configuration? Which module pulls in the security at all, if any? How to find out this bogus implicit dependency?

Answer (score 0):

Check that in the `pom.xml` file you do not include the dependency `spring-boot-starter-security`.

Answer (score 0):

Because you added Spring Security Dependency to your project but didn't config it.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
</dependency>
```